# Can I grant post only for ListCreateAPIView?

Tags: django-rest-framework

```
class DebtList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Debt.objects.all()    
    serializer_class = DebtSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, PostOnly,)
```

This is my view.
I want to grant POST only.
And my PostOnly class is beneath.

```
class PostOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method == 'POST'
```

But it doesn't work....
What's wrong? Help me!

Comment: Please, "it doesn't work" provides no clue to help you. Does it crashes ? Does it mean you can't POST ? Does it mean you can also GET ?

Comment: I can't POST and GET

Comment: It doesn't allow any method

Comment: If I click 'option' button, I can post there...